# Return a boolean from a JpaRepository method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query in an interface which extends `JpaRepository`. The method should ideally return a boolean value, but I can't figure out how to SELECT anything that gets automatically translated into `boolean`.

This works, although I have to call it as `Boolean.valueOf(hasKids(id))`:

```
// yuck. I wanted a boolean
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select 'true' from dual where exists("
          + "select * from child_table where parent_id = ?)")
String hasKids(long parentId);
```

How can I change this to the more natural return type?

```
boolean hasKids(long parentId);  // throws ClassCastException
```

**Update:**

the stacktrace is not very helpful IMHO because it's the usual nightmare of Hibernate proxies and AspectJ closures, but here's the relevant portion anyway.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1025.hasKids(Unknown Source)
    at com.bela.foo.bar.Service.ThingyServiceImpl.recordHasKids_aroundBody4(ThingyServiceImpl.java:85)
    at com.bela.foo.bar.Service.ThingyServiceImpl$AjcClosure5.run(ThingyServiceImpl.java:1)
...
```

Comment: have you tried Select 1 from

Comment: I tried it with a Spring repository and only your query - method signature boolean. Everything works. Can you post your exception stacktrace and your implementation.

Comment: @mh-dev I have tried `select 1` and also `select 'Y'` and in both cases I get a ClassCastException

Comment: return type should be boolean, but can you post the whole exception

Comment: And for which query is this exception?

Comment: `select 'true'` or `select 'Y'` i.e. select any char type. If I do `select 1` then the exception is the same except that the message is `java.lang.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

Comment: @swinkler, any further comment based on what I've posted since?

Comment: @Béla: Can you please post the ThingyServiceImpl (the repository class) as well as the entity. The stacktrace without any other implementation details is not helpful.

Comment: @swinkler adding as comment because honestly I can't see that it's relevant:

Comment: `@Service
@Transactional
public class ThingyServiceImpl implements ThingyService
{
  @Autowired
  ThingyRepository thingyRepository;

...

  @Override
  public boolean recordHasKids(Thingy thing)
  {
    return Boolean.valueOf(thingyRepository.hasKids(thing.getId()));
    //return thingyRepository.hasKids(thing.getId());
  }
}`

Comment: @Béla Well, I am really sorry but it seems that I can't help. As I said the same thing works fine with me. Sorry.

Comment: @swinkler No problems. Do you have a minimal working example you could give me? Perhaps this just comes down to versions of dependencies

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar problem.  My solution was to use a projection of java.lang.Boolean.

```
@Query("select new java.lang.Boolean(count(*) > 0) from child_table where parent_id = ?")
Boolean hasKids(long parentId);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Should the return type on the method be Boolean then?

Comment: Thank you @JordanMackie for catching my typo.  Yes, the return type should be Boolean.  I've updated my solution.

Comment: My solution was `SELECT new java.lang.Boolean(count(rui) = 0) FROM  table rui`

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to check the row exist or not for the parent id,and return true and false on the basis of that, then go for the **case**.

Changes to made in query

```
    "select case when (count(*) >0) then true else false end from dual where exists("
      + "select * from child_table where parent_id = ?)
```

Comment: This does not work on stupid databases that doesn't know about boolean. Oracle : ORA-00904: "FALSE" invalid identifier

Comment: @ihebiheb either move away from oracle (recommended), or code `select case when exists (...) then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual`

Answer (score 2):

I tested this by removing the single quotes around true and it works.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select true from dual where exists("
      + "select * from child_table where parent_id = ?)")
String hasKids(long parentId);
```

Comment: presumably you're using a database with a boolean type e.g. postgres? I'm confined to Oracle, which does not

Comment: @Béla you have my sympathy having to work with oracle, however you can just code the query as `select case when exists (...) then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual`

Comment: still doesnt work with oracle and native query "cannot cast String to Boolean". without quotes: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "N"

Answer (score 1):

With my Oracle constraint and a combination of all the suggestions here, I found a solution that worked for my situation without having to call Boolean.valueOf(hasKids(id)):

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select case when exists(select * from child_table " 
    + "where parent_id = :parentId) then 'true' else 'false' end from dual")
Boolean hasKids(@Param("parentId") long parentId);
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an issue, at least with mysql
(count(*) >0) convert to boolean fine when the query is non native
(count(*) >0) returns a "BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean" when the query is native

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to the question?